# How can i intercept an on-click asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have a component with a button which handles some stuff, i want to pass an interceptor to this component so i can call an `API` inside the interceptor and ask for permission, if permission is granted the code inside the component's button's onClick is executed and if not, well it is not
So right now i'm having trouble figuring out what to do, here is a sudo code showing what i want to do:

```
//Inside componentA which is using componentB
onClickInterceptor = () => {
    axios.post(//something)
        .then(response => {
            // do a few thing and finally you know if you should return true or not
        })
        .catch(error => {
            //you know you don't have permission
        })


    return //This is my problem, i don't know what to return, i don't want to return the axios post, i want something like a new promise ?        
}

//Inside componentB
onButtonClick = (event) => {
    if (this.props.onClickInterceptor) {
        this.setState({ disableButton: true })

        this.props.onClickInterceptor()
            .then(permissionState) => {
            if (permissionState) {
                this.runTheMainCode()
            }
            else {
                //dont do anything
            }

            this.setState({ disableButton: false })
        }
    }
    else    
        this.runTheMainCode()
}

this.runTheMainCode() {
    //...
}
```

Right now i don't know what to return inside **`onClickInterceptor`**, i know i don't want to to return the `axios`, but how can i return a promise like that which only returns `true` or `false` ?
By the way, i want the button to be disabled until the interceptor is done

Comment: You can return `true`, `false` or whatever you want in the axios then() callback. It will get sent to the next then() callback in the chain. No reason not to use it

Comment: Return a promise: `return axios.post(//something);`, so you can use then in your `onButtonClick `.

Comment: Otherwise, use `async/await`.

Comment: @PatrickEvans so you are saying i can do : return axios.post().then(response => return true).catch(error=>return false) ?

Comment: Yes, the value will be the argument in the `then()` callback in `onButtonClick`, ie `permissionState`

Comment: i wrote the full code on the answer, tell me if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the axios promise and handle it at the componentB

```
//Inside componentA which is using componentB
onClickInterceptor = () => {
    return axios.post(//something)
        .then(response => {
            // you can return false or true here
            return true 
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw error
        })      
}

//Inside componentB
onButtonClick = (event) => {
   this.props.onClickInterceptor.then(returnedBoolean=>{
   // here will come what you returned
      this.setState({ disableButton: returnedBoolean })
   }).catch(err=>{
   // the error hadnling ....
   this.setState({ error: true })
   })
}
```

Comment: Your answer worked, just one more thing, how can i return something in the interceptor like axios, meaning what if i don't want to use `axios`?, what should i return so it results in a `then` and an `catch`

Comment: You can use fetch too, anything that is asynchronous (a promise) should be implemented in the same way and it will work fine :).

Comment: I want to do a `setState` inside the `then`, and only return the value after the `setState` is completed,  how can i achieve this?

Comment: there is a setState callback for that  (google for more) :)
return this.setState({error: false} , () => {
  return true
})